# Help with differentiating old gray and yellowed pieces

Tags: part-identification, colour, quality

[image: LBG pieces][image: LBG pieces][image: LBG wheel rims]Hi everyone,
I'm having trouble deciding if those pieces are yellowed, old shades of gray, or just natural differences in color because of different LEGO batches. I'm skeptical of old gray because these pieces are from sets from around 2011-2015. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I soaked them in hydrogen peroxide in full sunlight for a couple of hours but there has been little to no effect.

Comment: To me, they all seem bluish gray (top foto dark, other fotoos light). I also can't see any yellowing. But I think something like that is really hard to determine from fotoos.

Comment: All of these seem to be in LBG and DBG colors. Keep in mind that due to production process (undesired) shade difference could be occur even with a same set, no to mention color difference of pieces produced in several years. Light/Dark Gray pieces are quite easy to distinguish once you get one in your hands.

Comment: Thanks for the answers :) I guess I will figure it out sooner or later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me the first picture seems to contain dark bluish gray pieces while the other two look like light bluish gray. Especially since the [Wheel 18mm D. x 14mm with Pin Hole, Fake Bolts and Shallow Spokes](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=55981&idColor=5#T=C) was never officially released in any of the old grays, just Light Bluish Gray (and a bunch of other colors that are impossible to mistake for old gray).

Additionally, [all](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3623#T=C) [the](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3710#T=C) [plates](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3020#T=C) [here](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3031#T=C) have been released in a lot more sets as their "bluish" versions than in the old "light/dark gray" colors, so unless your collection is known to be composed of older sets, statistically it's much more probable that a random sampling of these pieces would be the new, "bluish" versions. For example take a look at the *Plate 4 x 4*: it was released in more sets as light bluish gray, as in both old color variants together, and in even more sets as dark bluish gray. The number of pieces in those sets is even more extremely skewed.

| Color | # of sets | # of pieces |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dark Gray | 29 | 78 |
| Light Gray | 81 | 129 |
| Dark Bluish Gray | 438 | 946 |
| Light Bluish Gray | 349 | 764 |

Comment: Thank you very much :)